# .Net 6: too many warnings for variables could be null

Tags: c#, .net

I just upgraded a solution from .NET framework 4.8 to .NET 6.
There are too many warnings, even after I enable nullable in project file

`\<Nullable>enable\</Nullable>`

Is it safe to suppress all of them?

> Warning   CS8600  Converting null literal or possible null value to
> non-nullable type.
>
> Warning   CS8601  Possible null reference assignment.
>
> Warning   CS8602  Dereference of a possibly null reference.
>
> Warning   CS8603  Possible null reference return.
>
> Warning   CS8604  Possible null reference argument for parameter
>
> Warning   CS8618  Non-nullable field '' must contain a non-null value
> when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable.
>
> Warning   CS8622  Nullability of reference types in type of parameter
> 'state' of '' doesn't match the target delegate 'WaitCallback'
> (possibly because of nullability attributes).
>
> Warning   CS8625  Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference
> type.

Comment: The warnings are showing up because you have enabled the nullable checks. Simply, disable it if you don't want them.

Comment: `even after enable nullable in project file` so enabling the validation of nullable makes you believe that the warnings for nullable go away?

Comment: Nullable references were designed with great care to allow gradual opt-in, so as to not overwhelm people with barrels of warnings on existing code (as here), which would slow or prevent adoption. This means not using the global `enable` flag but introducing `#nullable enable` in individual files, or even individual sections, and introducing annotations before you introduce warnings. The docs have an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies) on how to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it safe to suppress all of them?

Safe is subjective. It will work like it always did; the same null reference bugs will exist with or without the warnings (and the number of those could be zero, if you're always perfect), so if you were happy without the warnings on .NET Framework: you are allowed to disable it.

The warnings are *trying to help you*, but I do accept that it can be overwhelming when enabling it on an existing large codebase. The option can also be controlled on a file-by-file basis via `#nullable enable` / `#nullable disable` if that helps. Personally, I've usually found it is worthwhile taking the time to process the warnings and fix any issues (which often just means marking some fields/parameters/locals as nullable, by adding a `?`) - but: it is up to you whether you decide not to do that - whether than means doing it some time in the future, or never doing it.